# Get database size of specific data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I read many threads about hwo to get the size (file size) of an table or Database.

What I want to know is, if there is a possility to select the size of only specific rows.

Some think like (pseudo code):

```
Select Size(*) from TableA where UserID = 10;
```

Does anybody know if this is possbile?

Regards Steffen

---**update**--------

Maybe ist a design weakness of my structure.

I have 1 table where many Customer insert data. Now I want to calculate some price based on the file size of the user inserted data.

Maybe there is a other way like some clustering or somethink else and then use some System table.
You may helped me with a little hint.

It is important that not every user has ist own Database.

Comment: You can get an approximation by multiplying the size of the table by the count of the rows you want and dividing all that by the count of all the rows in the table.  The problem is that some data types vary in size.

Answer (score 0):

A *very rough* guide would be to use the [`DataLength()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) function

```
SELECT DataLength(col1) + DataLength(col2) + ... + DataLength(colN)
FROM   your_table
WHERE  condition = true
```

If you want a total for the table then you just need to use aggregate functions as normal:

```
SELECT Sum(DataLength(col1) + DataLength(col2) + ... + DataLength(colN))
FROM   your_table
WHERE  condition = true
```

Comment: Thats to slow :(
I'm talking about a table with, at the moment, 432,018,309 rows.
I extendet my question a Little bit.

Comment: @Gordon2001  If that's too slow, then the Row-Count method is the only query-based that can possibly be fast enough.

Comment: @Gordon2001 I often use this script to calculate an *estimated* size of tables in a database. Find the size of the whole table then divide that by the number of rows for a given user to give you an *approximated* result.